# Multiple inner joins returning Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are the tables from my database:

[image]

I need following columns from the above tables as follows :

**tblVendor :** `Name` (AS `VendorName`)

**tblVendorItem :** `Name` ( AS `VendorItemName`)

**tblEvent :** `Name`( AS `EventName`) and `EventDate`

**tblEventService :** `ServiceDate` and `Status`

I have written the following query to retrieve the above data :

```
SELECT tblEvent.NAME               AS 'EventName',
       tblEvent.EventDate          AS 'EventDate',
       tblVendorItem.NAME          AS 'VendorItem',
       tblVendor.NAME              AS 'VendorName',
       tblEventService.ServiceDate AS 'Date',
       tblEventService.Status
FROM   tblEvent
       INNER JOIN tblEventService
               ON tblEvent.EventID = tblEventService.EventID
       INNER JOIN tblVendor
               ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
       INNER JOIN tblEventItem
               ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID
WHERE  tblEvent.CustomerID = @C_ID;
```

But i don't know why the sql engine returns the following error :

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The objects "tblEventService" and
>   "tblEventService" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use
>   correlation names to distinguish them.

What am i doing wrong here ? Or is the query itself wrong ?

Comment: The query you have provided looks fine. Is this the actual query? The error seems to state that there are multiple tables with the same name in the query `from` clause. Check to see that you haven't actually included  tblEventService twice.

Comment: is this your actual query? you would usually see a message like that if you join to the same table twice without using an alias to distinguish them.

Comment: The error is suggesting that your FROM clause contains 2 objects called 'tblEventService'. Have you changed your query?

Comment: @NathanKoop : I have multiple joins on/using the same table then ! what should i do in this case?

Comment: as a suggestion perhaps you may want to look at table Aliasing to make it easier to read your table and not use the `AS` key word.. but that's preference at that point

Comment: Why did you posted a different query that the one that's giving you an error?. If you are using the same table multiple times, then you should use aliases (or better yet, **always** use aliases for your tables)

Comment: your query only appears to link to `tblEventService` once, we are suggesting that the actual query might contain: `INNER JOIN tblEventService ON..... INNER JOIN tblEventService ON` so its joined to twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot to join table "tblVendorItem"

```
SELECT tblEvent.NAME               AS 'EventName',
       tblEvent.EventDate          AS 'EventDate',
       tblVendorItem.NAME          AS 'VendorItem',
       tblVendor.NAME              AS 'VendorName',
       tblEventService.ServiceDate AS 'Date',
       tblEventService.Status
FROM   tblEvent
       INNER JOIN tblEventService
               ON tblEvent.EventID = tblEventService.EventID
       INNER JOIN tblVendor
               ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
       INNER JOIN tblEventItem
               ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID
       INNER JOIN tblVendorItem
               ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendorItem.VendorID
WHERE  tblEvent.CustomerID = @C_ID;
```

Comment: But i need the column "VendorName" .. Your query works fine but i need that column ... What should i do??

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Obviously you should join the table `VendorItem`

Comment: I added it to how I think you want it joined

Comment: Arghh ... Silly question.. Thank you very much ... The query worked just fine !

Comment: Everyone has those blonde moments. Your welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: @StephanCalderon : exactly..!!! :D  I need one more favour .. as you have seen my database... In my `tblEventService` there will be all the items which will be in my Cart i.e. if there are three items in my event then there will be **three** entries(3 rows) in my `tblEventService` linked to **one** `EventID`.. How should i go about this ?

Comment: When you inner join, it will return all three rows. Do want that to happen or not?

Comment: @StephanCalderon : Actually that is the problem it doesn't return 3 rows , it returns more.. May be should i use multiple `AND` in `WHERE` ? .. because **One** customer will be linked to **one** event(for a instance) and that event will have a couple(say **three**) `EventServices` .. Am i explaining properly ? So in the `AND` i could check for `EventID AND CustomerID` ??

Comment: Okay I see. Well my guess is that it might be one of your other joins adding the extra rows. Try commenting out each join and it's columns respective columns in the select clause until you find which one is adding the extra rows

Comment: @StephanCalderon : i wrote a similar query which worked for me ! Please see my answer!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, use aliases when joining the same table, like this:

```
SELECT es1.EventID
FROM tblEventServices es1
JOIN tblEventServices es2
ON es1.EventID = es2.EventID --or however you wish to join them
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually referencing the same table more than once, you will need to provide an alias so that SQL Server can distinguish between the 2 references. Take this as an example:

```
SELECT ... -- some fields
       es1.ServiceDate AS 'Date',
       es2.Status
FROM   tblEvent
       -- 2 joins to same table
       INNER JOIN tblEventService es1 ON tblEvent.EventID = es1.EventID
       INNER JOIN tblEventService es2 ON tblEvent.EventID = es2.EventID
       -- some other joins
WHERE  ...
```

So joining to the same table twice is now distinguished with `es1` and `es2` aliases.

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted was to see number of `EventService` linked to one event . Here `EventService` will be the produucts in the `Event` .. So if there are two products then there will be two entries in `tblEventService` ..

I wrote the following query with the help from one of the answers by @Stephan Calderon :

```
SELECT tblEventService.ServiceDate,
       tblEventService.ServiceVenue AS 'SERVICE_VENUE',
       tblEventService.Status AS 'SERVICE_STATUS',
       tblEventService.CustomerRemarks AS 'CUSTOMER_REMARKS',
       tblEventItem.Quantity AS 'QTY',
       tblVendorItem.Name AS 'PRODUCT_NAME',
       tblVendorItem.Price AS 'PRICE',
       tblEvent.Name AS 'EVENT_NAME',
       tblCustomer.Name AS 'CCUSTOMER_NAME',
       tblEventType.Name AS 'EVENT_TYPE_NAME'

FROM tblEventService 

        INNER JOIN tblEventItem ON
                tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID

        INNER JOIN tblVendorItem ON 
                tblVendorItem.VendorItemID = tblEventItem.VendorItemID

        INNER JOIN tblEvent ON 
                tblEvent.EventID = tblEventService.EventID

        INNER JOIN tblCustomer ON
                tblEvent.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID

        INNER JOIN tblEventType ON
                tblEvent.EventTypeID = tblEventType.EventTypeID

WHERE tblEventService.EventID = @eventID;
```

This query yields the required result as below :

[image]

Thank You everyone!